# Adding folder of snippets to snipmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, snipmate

snipmate comes with a ton of snippet files.  This covers most of the bases.  However I would like to add some snippet collections created by other users.   When I download these the snippets are broken down into and placed in folders instead.  I tried adding one of these folders to the location of the other snippet files (snipmate/snippets/) but it doesn't appear that VIM detected them.

I don't see much documentation on adding additional snippets so I must have overlooked something.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are probably looking for rails snippets, I'd suggest you the ones that [Mike Farmer](http://twitter.com/#!/mikefarmer) wrote. You can find them [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets).

You can install them easily by doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets.git

rake deploy_local
```

As you can see he wrote a rake task for it and it worked very well for me!

Comment: This works great.  I had a gross misconception of how the snippets work.  I expected respond_<tab>  to give me a respond_to block, when in fact its is rest<tab> that does this.